# How to display live video stream on iPhone using the IP?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, video-streaming, mpmovieplayer

THis is the IP address "http://64.xxxxx/pda.htm"

When I log into the browser, it asks me for a username.Then it works fine.

This is what I have on the iPhone, can someone please help me.

```
self.myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];

self.myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
self.myWebView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.myWebView];

NSURLRequest* r = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://64.183.101.142:81/pda.htm"] cachePolicy:nil timeoutInterval:20];

[self.myWebView loadRequest:r];
```

Comment: because pda.htm1does not exsist

Comment: @NiteshVerma I changed the URL  http://64.183.101.142:81/pda.htm

Comment: IT works on my broswer, but not in UIWebView I'm going nuts

Comment: But why it is initially encrypted in the question whats the use?

Comment: Never mind, are you running it on an emullator?

Comment: I have tried emulator and a device.